# ng switch is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, switch-statement

Here's a list of objects that's shown by `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="paymentinfo in paymentList | filter:keyword | filter:money | filter:getdate | filter:{state: archived.state}">
          <td>{{paymentinfo.date}}</td>
          <td ng-click="singlepage(paymentinfo.id)" ><a>{{paymentinfo.name}}</a> </td>
                  <td>
                      <div class="grey-flag remark-payment">
                          <div class="hover-remark">{{paymentinfo.remark}}</div>
                      </div>
                  </td>
          <td>$ {{paymentinfo.amount}}</td>
          <td id="outmouse">
              <ul  style="list-style: none;" class="gt-reset">
                <li class="dropdown changecoursename">
                    <a   class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="tableOperation norlmalstate">Open Course</span>
                    <span  class="tableOperation openedstate">more options</span>
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="tableOperation" ng-click="paymentRemarks()">Remarks</a></li>
                    <li><a class="tableOperation" ng-click="paymentReturn(paymentinfo)">Return</a></li>
                    <li >

                        <a  class="tableOperation" ng-click="paymentDelete(paymentinfo)">Delete</a>
                        <div ng-switch on="paymentinfo.archived">
                            <div ng-switch-when="archived">11</div>
                            <div ng-switch-default>222</div>
                            </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </td>
      </tr>
```

There I need to show one `div` when object has a param archived, and show another when object has another param

I tried to do this:

```
<div ng-switch on="paymentinfo.archived">
    <div ng-switch-when="archived">11</div>
    <div ng-switch-default>222</div>
</div>
```

But something is wrong in my code.

My JS

```
$scope.datas = [
    {date:'06-12-2016', name : 'Pinao Class', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 101, id : 21},
    {date:'15-04-2016', name : 'drivers Class', state: 'notarchived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 102, id : 22},
    {date:'24-03-2016', name : 'Airplane Class', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 103, id : 23},
    {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class', state: 'notarchived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 24},
    {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class1', state: 'notarchived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 241},
    {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class2', state: 'notarchived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 2432},
    {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class3', state: 'notarchived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 2342},
    {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class4', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 2443},
    {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class5', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 2243},
    {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class6', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 2242}
];

$scope.paymentList = $scope.datas;
```

Comment: "But something is wrong in my code." What is that something? What isn't working?

Comment: the switching beetween <div ng-switch-when="archived">11</div>
                            <div ng-switch-default>222</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your switch variable:

```
<div ng-switch on="paymentinfo.state">
    <div ng-switch-when="archived">11</div>
    <div ng-switch-default>222</div>
</div>
```

because your paymentInfo object does not have an element with the key "archieved". ng-switch compares the value paymentinfo.state with the values in ng-switch-when statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `paymentinfo.state` instead of `paymentinfo.archived`

And here is an example for `ng-switch`: [JS Fiddle ng-switch](http://jsfiddle.net/javimuu/Lvc0u55v/13601/)